# Storing/serving web-site images securely and efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx, security

Hello web development gurus

What is the best practice for storing and serving images securely without hurting performance?

Is it possible to store user images in a folder that's not web accessible (possibly higher up and before /www?) and serve on demand after the user has logged in to the page? There is a username and password access mechanism already in place.

The users do not want these images to be publicly accessible.

I am running nginx with php on Ubuntu. Database is mysql.

Thank you!

Comment: try to avoid using a slow script on every single request to authenticate. http://www.vitki.net/book/page/pubcookie-module-nginx this would be very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a php file to serve those images and do some checks before serving them. I would try something like this:

```
<?php
if ( /* YOUR CHECK HERE */ ) {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); // Or whatever your content type might be
    readfile('/path/to/file');
}
```

You could the use RewriteRule's to make those calls to your php file look like real images:

```
rewrite /img/users/pictures/(.*) /your_php_file.php?path=$1 break;
```

Or something like that.

**This may be secure but not very efficient because your server has to access two file. The php file and the image file**

Comment: You could use `readfile` instead of `file_get_contents` followed by `echo`.

Comment: I think you meant RewriteRule and what is the 'break;' for?

Comment: He is using an nginx server. So he needs the syntax for his nginx.conf

Comment: Thank you!  Based on all the valuable input here I created an intermediate file like:

`<?php
    $file = basename(urldecode($_GET['file']));
    $fileDir = '/image/path/';

    if (file_exists($fileDir . $file))
    {
     header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        readfile($fileDir . $file);
    }
?>`

For security, in addition to this I am randomizing the image names and preventing direct access (permit access only from my domain).  Further, I am using the nginx configuration file to 'rewrite' the url. I don't get why this post was closed though.  Thanks for the great responses!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should evaluate the use of a CDN like Amazon S3, it provides secure acces via RESTful authentication: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html and avoid your server to do the job of serves static content.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do something like that is probably through Apache rewrite. When the user log in, you add an entry to a rewrite map keyed to the user's session id. The value of the entry points to the directory holding the images. You would have a rewrite rule that parse out the session id from the cookie and rewrites the URL to the image directory. Effectively then, you're making the directory web-access only to that user.

Anything that involves Apache rewrite is voodoo. Unless you really have that kind of traffic, it's not worth the complexity. Serving the files through PHP is inefficient but in many cases the inefficiency is tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what other requirements you have. You might want to let your users share their images by sending a link, so that only people that have this link, even not authenticated in your system, can see the images. Your proposed implementation would make this difficult.

If you are not too concerned about possible "leaks", you can generate random names to your images, and put all the effort in the true randomness of this, so that it is as hard to guess an image name as it would be to guess a password. On one side you can consider this "password protected", but bear in mind that your paths will be cached in proxies, browser history, etc... so this might not be the solution for you depending on the resources you are protecting.